# How to prevent a page break between a paragraph and the following table

Tags: java, itext

I am new to iText, currently doing a little project with it in java.

I am wanting to print out a table 'title' and then the table itself.  What is happening is that sometimes the data causes the table title to appear at the bottom of a page and the table to start on the next page.

I want to keep the table title and the table together, i.e. if there isn't room to start the table after the title then move both to the next page.

I am currently adding the title by creating a paragraph object, and then adding a PDFTable object after it.  I have tapped out some sample code below basically representing what I am doing at the moment:

```
// Add a table title
Paragraph tableTitle = new Paragraph();
tableTitle .setAlignment(1);
tableTitle .add("This is my table title");
tableTitle .setSpacingAfter(12);
try {
    document.add(tableTitle );
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    throw new ReportingException("Couldn't add section title", e);
}

// Now add the table
PDFTable currentTable = new PdfPTable(3);
// add the headers and data to the table etc...
:
:
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you are new to iText, it would be best to start with iText 7 and not with iText 5. I know that you're using iText 5, because I see that you use `PdfPTable`.

iText 7 is not compatible with previous versions. iText 5 was rewritten from scratch to solve a number of known technical issues for once and for all. As you are new to iText, that shouldn't matter to you: you don't have any old code that needs to be migrated from version 5 to 7.

You can learn more about using iText 7, by reading the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks) tutorial. In [Chapter 4](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-4-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-1), you will discover the `setKeepWithNext()` method. In this tutorial, this method is used to keep the title of a chapter on the same page of the first paragraph of that chapter:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(SRC));
String line;
Div div = new Div();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    document.add(new Paragraph(line)
        .setFont(bold).setFontSize(12)
        .setMarginBottom(0)
        .setKeepWithNext(true));
    div = new Div()
        .setFont(font).setFontSize(11)
        .setMarginBottom(18);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        div.add(
            new Paragraph(line)
                .setMarginBottom(0)
                .setFirstLineIndent(36)
        );
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            document.add(div);
            break;
        }
    }
}
document.add(div);
```

If you insist on using iText 5, you could use a workaround, but that will make your code more complex. Workarounds could involve using `ColumnText` (but the number of lines in your code will increase significantly), adding the table title as a header row (but then the title will be repeated if the table is distributed over different pages), wrap the title and the table in another object that is "kept together" (but that doesn't always work, depending on how much data is stored in the combined object).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the chapter, but don't add it directly to the document. So you can control the page break. See the code:

```
    document.add(chapter.getTitle());
    for(Element e : chapter) {
        document.add(e);
    }
```